Lombok and field prefix "has"
I have request payload object which has boolean property starting with has and I use Lombok annotations like @Builder, @Data, @AllArgsConstructor ...
When I am sending request having property set to "true" I get null.
Example:
I am sending smth like
{ "hasName": true; ... }
My Dto is like:
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Payload {
   @JsonProperty("hasName")
   private Boolean name;
    ...
}

And I am getting this:
name=null

How to make this work correctly and instead of null get true for boolean value?

What are you using for deserialization? Jackson?

It is just request payload :
Like
public Response  process(
@Valid Payload payload,
...
){...}

Hope you are using @RequestBody tag along with @Valid tag.

yes, it is in place

I tried to regenerate the issue, however i was not able to.
Check all the imports you did, make sure all are from spring package.
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

See the example; it returns true
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Payload {
   @JsonProperty("hasName")
   private Boolean name;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       String s = "{ \"hasName\": true  }";
       Payload payload = objectMapper.readValue(s, Payload.class);
       System.out.println(payload.getName());
  }

}

With Object mapper it will, but for example if you try to send request with Postman and have this as body, it will not
